# WKWebView: how to disable Prevent cross-site tracking?

Tags: swift, wkwebview

My app has 1 ViewController that loads a web app url that uses Auth0 to handle login. In iOS 13.3, the webView has since stopped working to load other pages after login.

However, when I tried using Safari on Mac, the webapp works if I disable Prevent cross-site tracking. How can I do this in WKWebView?

[image: preferences]

```swift
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    private var webView: WKWebView!
    private var webViewConfiguration: WKWebViewConfiguration = {
        let source: String = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');" +
            "meta.name = 'viewport';" +
            "meta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no';" +
            "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" + "head.appendChild(meta);";
        let script: WKUserScript = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
        let userContentController: WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
        let conf = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        conf.userContentController = userContentController
        userContentController.addUserScript(script)
        return conf
    }()

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
    }

    private func setupView() {
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        title = "My App"
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(webView)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: webView)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: webView)

        // Adding deviceId and deviceName for analytics
        let endpointString = AppSettings.appUrl + "/?deviceId=\(deviceId)&deviceName=\(deviceName)"
        let escapedUrlString = endpointString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""

        if let url = URL(string: escapedUrlString) {
            Logger.log(message: "Loading with url - \(escapedUrlString)", event: .info)
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }
}

extension MainViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        shouldShowNativeError = false
        if let url = webView.url?.absoluteString {
            Logger.log(message: "didFinish loading url: \(url)", event: .info)
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        if let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust {
            let exceptions = SecTrustCopyExceptions(serverTrust)
            SecTrustSetExceptions(serverTrust, exceptions)
            let credential = URLCredential(trust: serverTrust)
            completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
        } else {
            completionHandler(.useCredential, nil)
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url,
            let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false),
            let scheme = components.scheme {

            if scheme == "blob" {
                self.blobItemUrl = url
                navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
                navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem
                navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareBarButtonItem
            }
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Comment: From auth0 community, the only way is to relax the security preference https://community.auth0.com/t/failed-silent-auth-login-required/33165

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
self.webView.configuration.processPool.perform(Selector(("_setCookieAcceptPolicy:")), with: HTTPCookie.AcceptPolicy.always)
```

Put it in "setupView()", after "webView.navigationDelegate = self"

EDIT : Apparently, you can't use this if you want to publish your app in App Store

Comment: Isn't it a private API, will App Store allow this,?

Comment: You will get rejected if you use any private apis.

Comment: This does not work on iOS 17.4, maybe Apple removed it.